# Relative file paths for linked assets in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, asset-management

I would like to link external assets relatively rather than absolutely in Illustrator.

Is that possible?

Comment: It's not the cleanest solution, but it used to find links at the top of its directory. You can also handle smart relinking with a combo of shellscript and js.

Answer (score 4):

After experimenting with Packages, I found that **Illustrator will always look for a "Links" or "links" folder** with placed files.

It has to be in the same folder as the AI document.

You can them move the Illustrator file and its placed files where you want and every time you open the AI file the links will be automatically updated.

Illustrator will only look for a "Links" folder if the original, absolute, links are broken.

Answer (score 1):

No. I think Illustrator links are always absolute...

However, I would suggest you to make a package (File > Package) and then open the AI file inside the generated folder and see if links changed to relative.

Comment: Note that Packaging a project in Illustrator is only available from CS6 and CC.
CS5 and below doesn't have this option but there is a script in ste scripting samples filder named CollectForOutput.
(I wanted to comment but im not allowed)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put the files in the same folder as the .ai file, but it 's not very organized. But check the [answer of MikeGondek is the Adobe forum for the full answer](https://forums.adobe.com/message/3316597#3316597).

Also for packaging in older CS versions, like CS4 & CS5, you can use the CollectForOutput, like dichterDichte said in this comment, located in Applications > Illustrator CS4 > Scripting > Sample Scripts > AppleScript, like [posted by Jo](http://jokographic.com/?p=270).

Hope this helps for some one!